# DateTime.parse giving Wrong Date

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, parsing, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching date from Firestore in string format
then i am casting in DateTime
but DateTime.parse()  giving me wrong date

The actual date is (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm) = 2022-01-29 15:23
The output is (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm) = 2024-05-01 15:23

Can you explain why it is giving

Comment: Nobody can tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show the exact string you're trying to parse along with the code you used to parse it.

Comment: Pleaqse provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it using DateFormat.parse(), like this:

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

then:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

DateTime dateTime = dateFormat.parse("2019-07-19 8:40:23"); // <-- your string inside
```